# Check if list of IP addresses fall within a list of CIDR notated IP blocks in R

Tags: r, iptools

I have a list of approximately 200 CIDR IP blocks for my company. I am trying to verify whether the visitors to a webpage (several thousand hits a day) are coming from those blocks or not. Ideally, the output I'd like is a percent not in range and a list of those IPs so I could check further on them.

I've found the `ip_in_range()` function from iptools package but it is a 1 to 1 comparison. I think that some sort of lapply or other loop should be able to accomplish what I want, but I am a novice an have not been able to come up with the right notation so far. I believe I would want to take IP#1 and test it against the various CIDR. Once it gets a TRUE, it could be stopped, but this isn't going to be repeated so often that I can't just cycle through all the blocks. Then the loop would go to IP#2 and go again. Truthfully, my failure rate is expected to be low enough that even just an output of TRUE and FALSE beside each IP would be enough for me to pull out the failures manually.

I know there has to be some generic method already for looping a function that takes 2 inputs, I just couldn't think of the right way to phrase the search to find anything.

Example data:

```
visitor_ip_addresses <- c("10.10.1.2", "10.34.21.4", "192.168.23.34", "172.16.34.78", "1.2.3.4", "192.168.4.6")
ip_ranges <- c("10.0.0.0/8", "192.168.0.0/16", "172.16.0.0/12")
```

Comment: Thx for poking at the pkg! Take a look at the [version of it on GitHub](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/iptools). it has two new functions that i think do what you're asking. if not, file an issue and we'll work on accommodating your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/iptools")

library(iptools)

visitor_ip_addresses <- c("10.10.1.2", "10.34.21.4", "192.168.23.34",
                          "172.16.34.78", "1.2.3.4", "192.168.4.6")

ip_ranges <- c("10.0.0.0/8", "192.168.0.0/16", "172.16.0.0/12")

ips_in_cidrs(visitor_ip_addresses, ip_ranges)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

ip_in_any(visitor_ip_addresses, ip_ranges)
## # A tibble: 6 × 2
##             ips in_cidr
##           <chr>   <lgl>
## 1     10.10.1.2    TRUE
## 2    10.34.21.4    TRUE
## 3 192.168.23.34    TRUE
## 4  172.16.34.78    TRUE
## 5       1.2.3.4   FALSE
## 6   192.168.4.6    TRUE
```

There's a reason there are two different functions for this that we haven't documented yet, but one uses some clever math and the other uses tries. I'd test each to see which performs better for production use.

Comment: Wonderful. I had a bit of an ordeal getting everything installed (update packages, install tibble, etc) but I got there.
My output was actually switched from yours, ips_in_cidrs gives a tbl_df and ip_in_any gives the list, but this seems to be perfect. They both gave the same sum, so integrity looks good. I just have more failures than I expected, so more work for me.

Comment: Glad it helped (and i probably just mis-pasted output chunks). It'll be on CRAN in October, so binaries for Win & macOS will be avail then. If you have more feature requests, don't hesitate to file an issue.